# How to have two foreign key references to the same model in Active Record migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 4.  I have a User model.  Now I want to create a new model called Following.  The table `followings` would have the columns `user_id` and `followed_user_id`, which are foreign keys referencing records in the `users` table.

I have a Active Record migration to create the `followings` table, like

```
class CreateFollowings < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :followings do |t|
            t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
        end
    end
end
```

This will create the column `user_id`.  How do I use the `t.references` syntax to create the `followed_user_id` column?

This isn't a question specific to Rails 4.  So if this is possible in Rails 5 or Rails 3, please comment as well.

I'm not asking about how to set up the models.  This question only concerns with the migration and setting up the table in the database.

Comment: Try `t.references :followed_user, index: true, foreign_key: true, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "followed_users" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Try change your migration like this:

```
class CreateFollowings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :followings do |t|
    def up
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :followed_user, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

And your model should also have same belongs_to relation in it.
So add following association in your models.

Followeing Model:

```
class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :followed_user, class_name => 'User'
end
```

User Model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :class_name => 'Following', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :followed_users, :class_name => 'Following', :foreign_key => 'followed_user_id'
end
```

**Another way to create foreign key below:**

```
def change
  add_foreign_key :followings, :users, column: :followed_user_id
end
```

[Api dock here.](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key)

Comment: You have `def up` within `create_table`?  Have you even tried to run this migration?  I'm not interested in setting up the models.  My question is only about the migration.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use `t.references` syntax to create `followed_user_id` column without exists of `followed_users` table. Even if you can use that syntax, you still must set up associations in models.

What problem is if you create 2 columns and add index for them:

```
class TestFollowing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :following do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, index: true
      t.integer :folowed_user_id, index: true
    end
  end
end
```